# Render Point Density to Texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, volumetrics, point-clouds

Was curious if anyone knows of a way to render out a point density to a 3dTexture for use in a game engine?

Usually these are just rendered to a red channel and then imported into a 3d texture in opengl just curious if blender has the ability to output these volumes to a texture as well.

Comment: for anyone coming back to this, this is the closest i have found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAvnrfHiXBM